# How to find an Xml Element when it's prefixed with a namespace?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt, xpath

I have an Xml File as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ea:Stories ea:WWVersion="2.0" xmlns:aic="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInCopy/2.0" xmlns:ea="urn:SmartConnection_v3">
<ea:Story ea:GUID="D8BEFD6C-AB31-4B0E-98BF-7348968795E1" pi0="style=&quot;50&quot; type=&quot;snippet&quot; readerVersion=&quot;6.0&quot; featureSet=&quot;257&quot; product=&quot;8.0(370)&quot; " pi1="SnippetType=&quot;InCopyInterchange&quot;">
<ea:StoryInfo>
<ea:SI_EL>headline</ea:SI_EL>
<ea:SI_Words>4</ea:SI_Words>
<ea:SI_Chars>20</ea:SI_Chars>
<ea:SI_Paras>1</ea:SI_Paras>
<ea:SI_Lines>1</ea:SI_Lines>
<ea:SI_Snippet>THIS IS THE HEADLINE</ea:SI_Snippet>
<ea:SI_Version>AB86A3CA-CEBC-49AA-A334-29641B95748D</ea:SI_Version>
</ea:StoryInfo>
</ea:Story>
</ea:Stories>
```

As you can see all elements have "ea:" which is a namespace prefix.

I'm writing an XSLT file to show the SI_Snippet text which is "THIS IS THE HEADLINE".

How to write the xpath in the XSLT file? Should it contain the namespace or should it be excluded?

```
//ea:Story[ea:SI_EL='headline']/ea:SI_Snippet or 
//Story[SI_EL='headline']/SI_Snippet
```

Actually both fail in the online tool I used: http://xslt.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php

So there should be another way?

If later, how does it know which namespace to look at? Should I be passing the namespace to the XslTransformer at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare the namespace in your XSLT and then use the prefix that you give it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ea="urn:SmartConnection_v3">
    <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:value-of select="//ea:Story[ea:SI_EL='headline']/ea:SI_Snippet" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- ...  -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the `xmlns:ea="urn:SmartConnection_v3"` in the root element.  This is important.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `XDocument`?

```
var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes""?>
<ea:Stories ea:WWVersion=""2.0"" xmlns:aic=""http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInCopy/2.0"" xmlns:ea=""urn:SmartConnection_v3"">
<ea:Story ea:GUID=""D8BEFD6C-AB31-4B0E-98BF-7348968795E1"" pi0=""style=&quot;50&quot; type=&quot;snippet&quot; readerVersion=&quot;6.0&quot; featureSet=&quot;257&quot; product=&quot;8.0(370)&quot; "" pi1=""SnippetType=&quot;InCopyInterchange&quot;"">
<ea:StoryInfo>
<ea:SI_EL>headline</ea:SI_EL>
<ea:SI_Words>4</ea:SI_Words>
<ea:SI_Chars>20</ea:SI_Chars>
<ea:SI_Paras>1</ea:SI_Paras>
<ea:SI_Lines>1</ea:SI_Lines>
<ea:SI_Snippet>THIS IS THE HEADLINE</ea:SI_Snippet>
<ea:SI_Version>AB86A3CA-CEBC-49AA-A334-29641B95748D</ea:SI_Version>
</ea:StoryInfo>
</ea:Story>
</ea:Stories>";

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml.ToString());
XElement v = xdoc.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "SI_Snippet");
```

**EDIT**

```
XPathNavigator navigator = xmldDoc.CreateNavigator();
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(navigator.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("ea", "urn:SmartConnection_v3");
var v = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ea:SI_Snippet", ns);
```

Comment: I understand if you'll want to scream! but I'm using .NET 1.1 for this project so XDocument doesn't exist and need to use XPaths in XSLT.

Comment: @TheLight well according to the OP my answer works ;) Other than that, try my edit?